# Using AJAX on frontend: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest deprecation except for admin role

Tags: functions, ajax, single

Everything is happening in single.php. I have to validate if user has subscribed to the webinar and show login button accordingly. It's on the frontend.

I'm doing this on document ready:

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()): ?>
    var data = {
        webinar: <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>,
        user: <?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>,
        action: 'enter_webinar',
    }

    $.ajax({
        url : '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type : "get",
        data: data,
        success: function(r) {
            $('#placeholder').html(r);
        }
    });
<?php endif; ?>
```

Div with ID `placeholder` is empty by default. This is what I have in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_enter_webinar', 'enter_webinar' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_enter_webinar', 'enter_webinar' );
function enter_webinar() {
    // conditional statment happens here
    // if condition is true, send this via AJAX:
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Enter webinar</a>
<?php
    wp_die();
}
```

When I login as an admin user, everything works perfectly: AJAX request is sent, conditional statements work correctly, the data is retrieved and a login button is show in `placeholder` div. For other roles, homepage of the website is displayed inside the `placeholder` div as an iframe and Chrome displays this error message in console log:

```
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can try setting `async: true,` in the ajax call to fix the error message you're getting.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett I already tried doing that. Warning message doesn't go away. The message itself doesn't bother me, the problem is that success function doesn't work properly. I need to display the login button using AJAX response.